# Promise resolve not waiting for promise inside it

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, request

I am trying to make a rest call and update a list and then resolve the promise with the updated list.

```
function addTestCaseToTestRail(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        compareTestRailAndProtractor().then(function(tests){
            var testsLength = tests.tests.length;
            var url = testRailURL+testRailData.addTestEndPoint;

            for(var i=0; i<testsLength; i++){
                if(tests.tests[i].id==undefined){
                    var newId=""
                    var options = {
                        url:url,
                        headers:headers,
                        body:{
                            "title":tests.tests[i].name,
                            "custom_jira_component" : 465
                        },
                        json: true
                    }
                    request.post(options, function(err, httpResponse, body){
                        if (err) {
                            console.error(err);
                            return;
                        }
                        newId = body.id;
                    });
                    tests.tests[i].id = newId;
                }
            }
            resolve(tests);
        });
    });
}

function test(){
    addTestCaseToTestRail().then(function(tests){
        console.log(tests);
    });
}

test()
```

The request is getting posted and I am able to create tests in test rail but the resolve(tests) does not have the newId assignment. 
This is the output I am getting. Not sure why resolve does not wait for the rest call to complete.

```
{ tests: 
    [ { id: '', name: 'test1'},
      { id: '', name: 'test2'},
      { id: '', name: 'test3'},
      { id: '', name: 'test4'},
      { id: '', name: 'test6'},
      { id: '', name: 'test5'} ] }
```

Comment: What should occur if `if(tests.tests[i].id==undefined)` evaluates to false?

Comment: nothing, just keep iterating with the loop. We can assume all the id are undefined

Comment: You're resolving the promise BEFORE any of your calls to `request()` are actually done.  They are async.  They finish sometime later AFTER your `for` loop is done.  There are dozens of other questions/answers that show how to handle this type of problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compareTestRailAndProtractor` returns a `Promise`. You can use `async/await` within `.then()` and `Promise` constructor within `for` loop to await `request` callback, which is issue at code at Question, as the `for` loop does not await the callback function

```
function addTestCaseToTestRail() {
  return compareTestRailAndProtractor()
    .then(async function(tests) {
        var testsLength = tests.tests.length;
        var url = testRailURL + testRailData.addTestEndPoint;

        for (var i = 0; i < testsLength; i++) {
          await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              if (tests.tests[i].id == undefined) {
                var newId = ""
                var options = {
                  url: url,
                  headers: headers,
                  body: {
                    "title": tests.tests[i].name,
                    "custom_jira_component": 465
                  },
                  json: true
                }
                request.post(options, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
                  if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                  }
                  newId = body.id;
                  tests.tests[i].id = newId;
                  resolve();
                });

              } else {
                resolve()
              }    
          });
      }
      return tests
    })
}

function test() {
  addTestCaseToTestRail()
    .then(function(tests) {
      console.log(tests);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err)
    })
}

test()
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it's because of the non-blocking nature of Javascript. The thing is that "resolve(test)" gets executed before your "post" event has a response (which is the one where you take the Id from).

I would recommend you to take a look at https://caolan.github.io/async/ Async is an amazing library for handling async processes.

Good luck!

**EDIT:** You can also take a look at [async/await](https://javascriptasyncfunction.com/) JS operators

Comment: This isn't really a solution.  Plus recommending the `async` library when the OP is already using promises and we have `async/await` doesn't really make sense.